# Getting data from firebase in androd studio

Tags: android

How to get data from firebase?
I can implement some data on it, but I do now know why I cannot get and put it in my activity, application.

This is my ValuEventListener, should I use here Livedata?

```
class FirebaseDB : LiveData<List<Shopping>>() {

    var fbItemCount:Long = 0
    private val firebaseDB2: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    private val userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
    public val ref = firebaseDB2.getReference("user/"+userID.toString())

    fun removeAll() {

    }

    fun delete(shopping: Shopping){

    }

    fun modify(shopping: Shopping) {

    }

    fun add(shopping: Shopping) {
        ref.child(shopping.id.toString()).setValue(shopping)
    }

    fun getShopping(): List<Shopping> {
            val lista: ArrayList<Shopping> = ArrayList()

        ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (messageSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val shopping: Shopping = Shopping(id = messageSnapshot.child("id").value as Long,
                        product = messageSnapshot.child("product").value as String,
                        quantity = messageSnapshot.child("quantity").value as String,
                        price = messageSnapshot.child("price").value as String,
                        bought = messageSnapshot.child("bought").value as Boolean)

                        //Log.i("readDB", "$product $quantity $price $isbought")
                    lista.add(shopping)

                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.e("MyAdapter", "Failed to delete value.",error.toException())
            }

        })

        fbItemCount = lista.size.toLong()

        return lista

    }

}
```

How can i check if it is downloaded somewhere on my app or I just cannot see it or implement well.

EDIT:

I just added log.v... and it starts working...
However after adding a new element in the list, new element is added with double information from firebase for example:

In database I have:
Orange
Apples

I add:
Bananas

Now in application it is like:
Orange
Apples
Orange
Apples
Bananas

Comment: Refer official firebase documentation it is well framed and descriptive.If you it difficult follow some medium article

Comment: I have done it. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write Every line of my code depend on documentation.

Answer (score 0):

About your double items problem this code making it because before making `ValueEventListener` you created an empty list then after get data from firebase in `onDataChange` method you add all items that firebase returns then suppose you add a new item by calling 'add' method them `onDataChange` will be triggered again and giving you again all items with a new one added, but you never remove the old item and add these new items again to this list. That's why it's happening

```
val lista: ArrayList<Shopping> = ArrayList()
    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (messageSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                val shopping: Shopping = Shopping(id = messageSnapshot.child("id").value as Long,
                    product = messageSnapshot.child("product").value as String,
                    quantity = messageSnapshot.child("quantity").value as String,
                    price = messageSnapshot.child("price").value as String,
                    bought = messageSnapshot.child("bought").value as Boolean)

                    //Log.i("readDB", "$product $quantity $price $isbought")
                lista.add(shopping)
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e("MyAdapter", "Failed to delete value.",error.toException())
        }
    })
```

Correct code would be like this:

```
var lista = emptyList<Shopping>()
    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

        lista = emptyList()

            for (messageSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                val shopping: Shopping = Shopping(id = messageSnapshot.child("id").value as Long,
                    product = messageSnapshot.child("product").value as String,
                    quantity = messageSnapshot.child("quantity").value as String,
                    price = messageSnapshot.child("price").value as String,
                    bought = messageSnapshot.child("bought").value as Boolean)

                    //Log.i("readDB", "$product $quantity $price $isbought")
                lista.add(shopping)
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e("MyAdapter", "Failed to delete value.",error.toException())
        }
    })
```

Comment: If I make like this I cannot use function add, lista.add(shopping)

Comment: If I write val lista = ArrayList<Shopping>() then it is still an error on my list Type mismatch: inferred type is List<Shopping> but LiveData<List<Shopping>> was expected

Comment: Here is a problem:
val liveData: LiveData<List<Shopping>>
        liveData = MutableLiveData()
        liveData.value = viewModel.allShopping

Comment: and here val allShopping: LiveData<List<Shopping>>

    init {
        repo = ShoppingRepo(FirebaseDB())
        allShopping = repo.getShopping()
    }

Comment: I have checked all kind of options and really don't understand it, if you have any idea plz msg. Thanks.

Comment: i m not getting your point plz add more code to your question to properly understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

`onDataChange` is an async callback and does not result in the same thread, so return one `liveData` and observe it, then in the on data change process the list and post it on the `liveData`.

```
fun getShopping(): LiveData<List<Shopping>> {
            val lista: ArrayList<Shopping> = ArrayList()
            val data=MutableLiveData<List<Shopping>>()


        ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (messageSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val shopping: Shopping = Shopping(id = messageSnapshot.child("id").value as Long,
                        product = messageSnapshot.child("product").value as String,
                        quantity = messageSnapshot.child("quantity").value as String,
                        price = messageSnapshot.child("price").value as String,
                        bought = messageSnapshot.child("bought").value as Boolean)

                        //Log.i("readDB", "$product $quantity $price $isbought")
                    lista.add(shopping)
                }
               fbItemCount = lista.size.toLong()
               data.postValue(lista)
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.e("MyAdapter", "Failed to delete value.",error.toException())
            }

        })


        return data

    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot implement LiveData on ViewModel right now it is private val repo: ShoppingRepo

 
    val allShopping: LiveData<List<Shopping>>

    init {
        repo = ShoppingRepo(FirebaseDB())
        allShopping = repo.getShopping()
    }

Comment: Type mismatch: inferred type is List<Shopping> but LiveData<List<Shopping>> was expected

Comment: FireBase is also LiveData
class FirebaseDB : LiveData<List<Shopping>>()